# Put Action for UITextfield when pressing on it

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I've a textfield and I want to give it action when I just **press** on it.

I tried two things:
1) to give it action when TouchUpInside.

```
[_countryTF addTarget:self action:@selector(testing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and

```
-(IBAction)testing:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"testing");
}
```

but testing action not getting called.

2) I tried to handle it with notifications like these

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideHandler:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

and

```
- (void) keyboardWillHideHandler:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //show another viewcontroller here
    NSLog(@"%@",notification.userInfo);

}
```

but um not getting any information about who fired the notification so I can make my action for my specific UITextField and not any other UITextField.

So any ideas ?

Comment: Tag your UI text fields, check which text field is first responder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use UIGestueRecognizer. textFieldDidBeginEditing: method will work just when you press text field first time. Add tap gesture recogniser to your text field:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(testing:)];
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [textField addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Now you needy to handle show keyboard manually. Add this code to your testing: method:

```
-(IBAction)testing:(id)sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = (UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    UITextField *tf = (UITextField*)[gr view];
    [tf becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"testing");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `UITextField Delegate methods`. Set the delegate of the textfield to the view controller class and implement this method

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField // Tells the delegate that editing began for the specified text field.
```

Comment: This answer will work just when you press on text field firs time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideHandler:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:myTextField];
```

And access the textField in your notification via:

```
- (void) keyboardWillHideHandler:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UITextField *textField = notification.object;
}
```

This will only handle the first tap. After the textField has been highlighted and the keyboard shown, following touches will not register. If you are only looking to make an initial reaction to the touch, this is an option. Otherwise, you should probably use a UITapGestureRecognizer like Greg explained.